# Wamp 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache2, wamp

I have formated the PC and I installed again WAMP. I have a project, created the DB, then imported my SQL DB. But now when I try to open again my project it shows this message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: First step would be to check your server error logs.

Comment: Did you follow the error message and take a look into the server error log?

Comment: This is really more a networking question, it might be better suited to [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The exact cause of the error will be in your apache error log

Check your apache configuration to fin out it's location

Comment: Where can I find the apache configuration ?

Comment: @marin on windows it would probably be in /yourprograms/wamp/http.conf or something liek that

Answer (score -3):

Some times the 500 error might be occurs because of database size limitations.